# Not able to filter messages based on header properties in Azure Stream analytics

Tags: iot, azure-iot-hub, azure-stream-analytics

I have created an Azure Stream Analytics (ASA) job to filter data based on a custom header property i send from a client app.

How would i read/filter message header properties in Azure stream analytics?
The portal return no results when i try to test out my query. Below is my query in azure portal.

So far this is my query as simple as this:

```
SELECT
    *
INTO
    [mystorage]
FROM
    [iothubin]
WHERE  Properties.type = "type1"
```

I also tried to call out the key without its parent (such as: where type = "") with no results as well.

I am sure that i am sending messages with this custom property in the header since i can view it using device explorer tool.

any idea how to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this yet myself, but supposedly you can access custom properties via `GetMetadataPropertyValue()`. Give this a try:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt793845.aspx

Comment: will give it a shot and will let you know if this works or not.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [query described here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/streamanalytics/2016/02/23/handling-json-array-in-stream-analytics-query/) as an example to query complex schemas.
If you share your schema, we can look at the query for you.

Let me know if it works for you.

Thanks,

JS